# Xml Deserilization is not working using Xstream

Tags: java, serialization, xstream, mime-message

I have a following class which is serializing

> org.springframework.integration.core.Message

into file as follows:

**Sample.java**

```
public static void receive(Message<?> message) throws IOException, MessagingException
{
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    File file = new File("c:/temp/temp.xml");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    xStream.toXML(message,fileOutputStream);
}
```

**UnMarshall.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MessagingException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    File file = new File("c:/temp/temp.xml");
    FileInputStream fileOutputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Message message = (Message) xStream.fromXML(fileOutputStream);
}
```

If I run UnMarshall.java then I am getting the following exception:

**Question**

- Is it possible to do serialize/deserialize Message object with XStream?
- If not what other options I have?

  Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:     Cannot construct class java.lang.Class
      ---- Debugging information ----
      message             : Cannot construct class java.lang.Class
      cause-exception     : java.lang.InstantiationException
      cause-message       : javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor
      class               : org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage
      required-type       : javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor
      path                : /org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage/payload/dh/dataContentHandler/dch/myDF
      line number         : 14
      -------------------------------
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ExternalizableConverter.unmarshal(ExternalizableConverter.java:110)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:66)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:188)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:125)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:66)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:188)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:125)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:66)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:188)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:125)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:66)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:188)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:125)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.AnnotationReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AnnotationReflectionConverter.java:66)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:188)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:125)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:56)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:45)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:46)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:117)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.ReferenceByXPathMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(ReferenceByXPathMarshallingStrategy.java:29)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:846)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:833)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:789)
          at org.springframework.integration.samples.mail.imapidle.DefaultEmailReceiverUtilService.main(DefaultEmailReceiverUtilService.java:103)
      Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor
          at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
          at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ExternalizableConverter.unmarshal(ExternalizableConverter.java:80)
          ... 39 more

Comment: Well, `Message` is just an interface containing two methods. So without knowing what you are actually trying to (un)serialize it is hard to answer. Do you have an example of the xml generated?

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue when I was googling for [my XStream bug](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/13). The problem here is that XStream is relying on the fact that ActivationDataFlavor claims to be Externalizable. But to fully be that it needs a public no-arg constructor, which is does not have, hence the java.lang.InstantiationException.

The good news is that the author of XStream worked around this. So if you use XStream 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT you should no longer run into this issue.

The bad news is that I've not yet found a way to get Oracle to notice that both [ActivationDataFlavor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/ActivationDataFlavor.html) and [PrivateMLet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/loading/PrivateMLet.html) do not fully respect the [Externalizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface. True, this public no-arg constructor requirement is quite hidden, but as you can see in above StackTrace, it's really needed

> When an Externalizable object is reconstructed, an instance is created
>   using the public no-arg constructor, then the readExternal method
>   called.